# Infura out of sync

Tags: infura, nonce

I have 13 transactions according to *[https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/[my_account]](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/%5Bmy_account%5D)*
and when I dispatch "eth_getTransactionCount" to *[https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/[my_project_id]](https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/%5Bmy_project_id%5D)* (with

```
"params": [
        "[my_account]",
        "latest"
    ]
```

)
I get back 9.

How to "update" or "sync" infura?

Comment: write to tech support and report this failure

Comment: I've found the answer! thanks for your comment anyway!

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer for my question:
[https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/52420/78856]

according to: [https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9c037b815fE3046806bc8230237553DDd1a71060] I have 13 transactions but 4 are inbound (IN) type of transaction. So it's alright!